Draw a One-period binomial asset pricing model with continuous dividend
I've copied the code below to draw the tree above:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=3cm, row sep=0mm, arrows={-Stealth}, cells={nodes={fill, circle, minimum size=3.5pt, inner sep=0pt, font=\small}}]
 & |["S_0u" above, "f_u" below]|&\\
|["S_0" above left, "f" below left]|\arrow[ur,"(P)" above left]\arrow[dr,"(1-p)" below left] \\
 & |["S_0d" above, "f_d" below]|&\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}

However, I'm really trying to recreate the image below with the drop in the second nodes, could you help me out please?


Welcome to tex.sx.

Could you tell us where you copied from? A link would be helpful.

Since you've not provided the content of your nodes, I don't know what is meant to be subscript and what not (which is a failure of the diagram, I suppose). But, anyway, I'd use forest, but there are other options. Certainly tikz-cd is among them.
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/715128/
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={math content,grow'=0},
  before typesetting nodes={
    for tree={
      circle,
      inner sep=1.5pt,
      s sep'+=20pt,
      fill,
      if level=0{% the root node
        label/.process={Ow{content}{left:$#1$}},
        l sep*=6,
      }
      {label/.process={Ow{content}{right:$#1$}}},
      delay={content={}},
    },
  },
  [S_{0}
  [uS_{0},grow'=-90, edge label={node [above,midway,sloped]{$p$}}
    [{S_{1(u)}=uS_{0(1-\delta)}}]
    ]
    [dS_{0},grow'=-90, edge label={node [below,sloped,midway] {$1-p$}}
      [{S_{1(d)}=dS_{0(1-\delta)}}]
    ]
  ]
  \coordinate [label=below:$t_0$] (a)  at ([yshift=-15pt]current bounding box.south -| !r.center);
  \coordinate  [label=below:$t_1$] (b) at (a -| {!r11.center});
  \draw [Bar-Bar] (a) -- (b);
\end{forest}
\end{document}

[This is a public service announcement on behalf of the EAFI. The existence failure of images in this post results from a bug in Okular 24 on X.]

Thanks very much, this worked! Happy days!
